# R Matching one column from three files and deleting all the rows where there is no match

Tags: r, match

So I have three csv files. The first column in each file is an ID column. I need to match the three ID columns and delete all the rows across the three files where there is no match in this column. So basically as long as the ID appears at least once in all three files you keep all the rows for that ID. For example;

**File A** ...........................**File B**........................**File C**

ID. X.... Y.... Z................ID....J....K....L............ID....T....U....V

1.. d..... d.... d.................1....d....d....d..............1....d.....d....d

2.. d..... d.... d.................1....d....d....d..............1....d.....d....d

3.. d..... d.... d.................1....d....d....d..............3....d.....d....d

4.. d..... d.... d.................2....d....d....d..............4....d.....d....d

5.. d..... d.... d.................2....d....d....d..............5....d.....d....d

.......................................3....d....d....d..............5....d.....d....d

.......................................4....d....d....d..............7....d.....d....d

.......................................7....d....d....d..............7....d.....d....d

Would Turn into;

**File A** ...........................**File B**........................**File C**

ID. X.... Y.... Z................ID....J....K....L............ID....T....U....V

1...d......d.....d.................1....d....d.....d.............1.....d....d....d

3...d......d.....d.................1....d....d.....d.............1.....d....d....d

4...d......d.....d.................1....d....d.....d.............3.....d....d....d

.......................................3....d....d.....d.............4.....d....d....d

.......................................4....d....d.....d..................................

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have read in each .csv as `fileA`, `fileB`, and `fileC`:

```
common_ids <- intersect(intersect(fileA$ID, fileB$ID), fileC$ID)

write.csv(fileA[fileA$ID %in% common_ids, ], "fileA_fixed.csv")
write.csv(fileB[fileB$ID %in% common_ids, ], "fileB_fixed.csv")
write.csv(fileC[fileC$ID %in% common_ids, ], "fileC_fixed.csv")
```